# Pick two random people in the world, what's the probability of them knowing each other?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have one question popped in my head out of nowhere at 3AM.

**If we pick two random people in the world, what's the probability of them knowing each other?**

You can assume that there are 7 billion people in the world and the idea of [Six Degrees of Separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_degrees_of_separation) is relevant, or maybe you can assume one person has a circle of friends up to 100 people. You can provide any other assumptions to make it simple.

Please help answer my 3AM thought so I can sleep peacefully.

Comment: You could think of it this way: Consider a randomly picked person on the planet. What is the probability that **you** know that person? Answer: The probability is equal to the number of people you know (100-200 people, max?), divided by the population of the planet (7.5 billion).

Comment: @MattiP. Nope, I think it's different. It's the probability of two random people knowing each other, not the probability of one particular person knowing another person. This is like the Birthday Paradox, but I put some twist on it (The Birthday Problem/Paradox: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofTb57aZHZs)

Comment: Do we assume that all people know know a fixed number of other people? If not, this could get complicated, as surely there are people who know, like, only 1 other person.

Comment: Sure, let's assume that one person usually know 100 people

Comment: You can assume anything as long as it answers the question @MattiP.

Comment: Well, I still think that it's this $\frac{100}{7.5\cdot 10^9}$. We pick two random people, let's call them person A and person B. They know each other if person A knows B and person B knows A. Perhaps we can also assume that "knowing a person" is a symmetric relation. So we only need to know wheter A knows B ... How many people does A know? A 100 people.

Comment: This is NOT like the birthday paradox, and @MattiP. is correct. Or, more precisely, this is similar to the birthday paradox in the case of $n=2$ people, which is the one case where there isn't really a paradox.

Comment: @jlammy Why is it not like the birthday paradox? Is it because of the symmetric relation?

Comment: As I said, it's like the birthday paradox where there are only $2$ people in the room. If you think about it, in that case there is no paradox. The reason the birthday paradox arises for, say, $n=23$ people is that the number of pairs of people who could share a birthday is $n(n-1)/2$. For $n=23$, this number is much larger than $n$ itself, which is where the apparent paradox comes from.

Comment: The symmetric relation has nothing to do with it. We have however to assume that every person knows $100$ people AND that every of those $100$ people know the particular person (because this is required : "they know each other") . This is surely not a realistic assumption, but in this case Matti's answer is trivially right.

Comment: The birthday paradox would come up if you had a big room and asked how many people need to be in the room for two of them to know each other.  The chance of any pair knowing each other is small, but the number of pairs is essentially half the square of the number of people.  You can invert the chance on pair knows each other, multiply by $2$ and take the square root.  That comes out around 60,000 people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to know is the average number of people the average person knows, plus the total population of the world. (By "knows" here, I am assuming a reciprocal relationship, discounting the fact that everyone "knows" lots of celebrities who don't know them from Adam.) If $K$ represents this average, and $P$ represents total population, then the answer is $K/(P-1)$.

To elaborate, just a bit, we have

$$K={1\over P}\sum_{i=1}^Pk_i$$

where $k_i$ is the (precise) number of people known to person $i$.  When you pick two people at random, the first person will be person $i$ with probability $1/P$, and the second person will be known to person $i$ with probability $k_i/(P-1)$, and thus the probability the two people will know one another is $\sum_{i=1}^P{1\over P}{k_i\over(P-1)}=K/(P-1)$.

As a practical matter, the probability is pretty small, probably well under one in a million.  Even if you restrict just to the U.S., the probability is likely to be around one in half a million: It has [been estimated](https://www.nytimes.com/2013/02/19/science/the-average-american-knows-how-many-people.html) that the average American knows about $600$ people.

Note, the six-degrees-of-separation phenomenon and the Birthday Paradox play no role here. They would have role if we were assembling (at random) some medium-sized group of people and asking, for example, for the probability that some pair of them are connected by a chain entirely within the group.

Comment: FWIW, the paper with the $600$ estimate can be found at https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3666355/

Comment: Thanks for the link! I found that paper very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are $n$ people in the world. Each individual is identified with a number $i$, $1 \le i \le n$. Let $k_i$ be the number of persons known by $i$, in a reciprocal way (i.e. if $i$ knows $j$ then $j$ knows $i$). The number of couples that know each other is:

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n{k_i}$$

because we count the couple $(i, j)$ twice, once for $i$ and once for $j$. Therefore the probability you are looking for is:

$$\frac{\frac{1}{2}{\sum_{i=1}^n{k_i}}}{{n \choose 2}}=\frac{\frac{1}{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n{k_i}}}{n-1}$$

i.e. it can be viewed also as the average number of people known (reciprocally) by an individual divided by all the other people ($n-1$).

Suppose you would like to compute the probability including one way knowing relationships. Each person $i$ will thus know $v_i$ "VIPs" or "influencers". Suppose the number of influencers is $m$ and that influencer $j$, $1 \le j \le m$, has $f_j$ followers. Then the above probability increases like this:

$$\frac{\frac{1}{2}{\sum_{i=1}^n{k_i}+\sum_{i=1}^n{v_i}}}{{n \choose 2}}=\frac{\frac{1}{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n{k_i}}}{n-1}+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n{v_i}}{{n \choose 2}}=\frac{\frac{1}{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n{k_i}}}{n-1}+\frac{\sum_{j=1}^m{f_j}}{{n \choose 2}}$$